# Is using href="javascript:" dangerous in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, security

From [the Angular security guide](https://angular.io/guide/security), there's this:

> To block XSS attacks, you must prevent malicious code from entering
>   the DOM (Document Object Model). For example, if attackers can trick
>   you into inserting a  tag in the DOM, they can run arbitrary
>   code on your website. The attack isn't limited to  tags—many
>   elements and properties in the DOM allow code execution, for example,
>   `<img onerror="...">` and `<a href="javascript:...">`. If
>   attacker-controlled data enters the DOM, expect security
>   vulnerabilities.

I've sometimes used `<a href="javascript:" (click)="someFunction()">link</a>` to target the element with CSS selectors (`a:link`) without the link referencing a URI, anchor, or running any code.

Is this a dangerous practice? They don't really give an example of how this could be exploited.

And if this is bad practice, then here's [my dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863094/targeting-javascript-bound-links-with-css-selectors-similarly-with-a-href-elemen): If I have a series of links in a nav, some of them ARE HREFs, and some of them bind to JS, but I want them all to look the same and use the same CSS selectors. Is there an easy way to accomplish that?

Comment: I know this doesn't address your question, but for me, it's not so much that it's a security risk as it is that it's an ancient technique that doesn't follow any of today's modern standards, best-practices or methodologies to web development. If all you want is something for the user to click on, use virtually any other kind of element and set up a `click` event handler for it in separated JavaScript. `a` is for navigation, not a JS hook.

Comment: But if I have a series of links in a nav, some of them ARE HREFs, and some of them bind to JS, but I want them all to look the same and use the same CSS selectors. Is there an easy way to accomplish that?

Comment: You can style anything to look like a link or a link to look like anything else. Styling is not a concern, using the appropriate tags for the content is what's important.

Comment: See **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4vr0Lnk/3/)** that shows how you can style an element to look like a link, but how to use a non-link element as a hook into running some JS.

Comment: Yes, but then you're adding additionel CSS rules for links and for HREFs.

Comment: That's not of any concern. You style the page the way it needs to be styled. You don't use the wrong tags because it means you can write less code.

Comment: But when more code means more maintenance or introducing more possibility of issues from future changes, it's a no-go for me.

Comment: Who said that the CSS will mean more maintenance or more possibilities of issues from future changes? If anything, this approach makes your code more flexible because using the correct markup allows you to modify styles with minimal disruption to the functionality. Always start with semantically correct HTML and quality content. Then, add CSS for presentation and finally JavaScript for behavior. This is how modern web applications are written.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an empty `href` for links that has (click)

```
<a (click)="action()" href>Previous</a>
```

If it doesn't work, you can try

```
<a href (click)="doSomething(); $event.preventDefault()">Link</a>
<a href (click)="!!doSomething()">Link</a>
<a href (click)="doSomething(); false">Link</a>
```

Comment: What will be the rendered value of `href`?

Comment: Replacing ```href="javascript:void(0)"``` with just ```href``` has prevented angular from prepending ```unsafe``` to the ```javascript:void(0)```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine.

This:

```
<a href="javascript:" (click)="someFunction()">link</a>
```

...*is not* an immediate security risk because you are not templateizing anything in your `href`.

This:

```
<a href="javascript:{{someVariable}}" (click)="someFunction()">link</a>
```

...*is* a security risk, because the `someVariable` value can be something malicious that was entered by a user and will now get executed on click.

That being said, why do you need to use `href="javascript:"` at all? Just use an Angular `(click)` event and call `preventDefault()` on the event object to stop it from doing that behavior you described.

```
<a (click)="doSomething($event)"><a/>

doSomething(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

**Update**

Scott Marcus makes some good points. You really shouldn't use an `a` element here at all because it requires some workarounds (such as the `preventDefault()`. The best tool in the toolbox here is a `span`.

Use it like so:

```
<span (click)="doSomething()"></span>
```

Comment: But while these work-arounds work, why do any of them? The minute a solution requires `event.preventDefault()`, it's a flag that you are not using the correct element. Links are for navigation, if you are just going to cancel the native behavior of your link in favor of some other operation, just use a semantically neutral element in the first place and set up a `click` event handler for it. Then we don't even have to have this conversation.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I agree completely. A regular `div` would be perfectly fine here as well and doesn't have any default behavior that needs to be prevented, and can still take a `(click)` event to do whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, but since we're trying to replace an `a`, I'd suggest a `span`.

Comment: Even better. Now, the only reason he may require an `a` is if he wants some kind of crawling to take place to follow the link...but that wouldn't make any sense given his question because he doesn't actually use a link value in the `href`. So, basically, yes, you're 100% right as far as this question is concerned.

Comment: My issue was also to do with CSS selectors and mixing element types, as mentioned in my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863094/targeting-javascript-bound-links-with-css-selectors-similarly-with-a-href-elemen