# Targeting JavaScript bound links with CSS selectors similarly with A/HREF elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I sometimes use `<a href="javascript:" onclick="someFunction()">link</a>` to target JS bound link with `a:link` CSS selectors, since targeting doesn't work on an element without the `href` attribute. However, this [can be dangerous in front-end frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862845/is-using-href-javascript-dangerous-in-angular-2?noredirect=1#comment88728410_50862845), and as someone pointed out, it's bad practice.

So, if I have a series of links in a nav, some of them *are* HREFs, and some of them bind to JavaScript, but I want them all to look the same and use the same CSS selectors. Is there an easy way to accomplish that without using `javascript:`? Using `href="#"` doesn't work either, because it links to the top of the page.

Comment: Why dont you use `href="#!"`

Comment: I haven't seen that before.

Comment: What's that called, and what does it do?

Comment: Give it a try. It will do the same as `#` without the scrolling to the top part

Comment: I would only use `<button>`

Comment: Or just do `event.preventDefault()` in the event listener, use a button, a styled div, etc. Many other options than using an anchor tag

Comment: @ivan buttons don't have a href, so then you're adding more code.

Comment: For the record, @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz suggestion works well with any character or string after the `#` character. `#whatever` would do the same thing as `#!` as long as those labels are not existing `id` in the DOM.

Comment: @Patrick Evans, That doesn't solve the security issues, and I think that's still bad practice.

Comment: What security issues? There are no security issues with what I suggested, not to mention there isn't anything with bad practice about them either.

Comment: As mentioned and linked in the question, it may be a security issue with front-end frameworks.

Comment: No, letting user added content into the dom is the security issue. Meaning allowing user added content into `href=""` or `onclick=""`. There is nothing breaking security by using a button, div, or even `preventDefault()`

Comment: @luis, care to answer my question? I'll vote.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, thanks. Please gander at my question about that.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862656/angular-2-security-is-it-safe-to-read-values-from-the-dom